# jQuery, submit is not cancelling on form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which I am trying to use JS to cancel, so that I can submit it using Ajax.

However I just started and as I made the form and tested to see if the submission is cancelled/return's false I discovered that it did not. I checked other threads/posts made but none helped me. This is my form bellow, followed by the .js file. The console in chrome has not given me any errors either.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the alert in the .js file is not coming up either.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="user-data-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="oldpassword">Old Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" id="oldpassword" name="oldpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Old Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-actions">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <!-- Submit element -->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary" value="Update">
            <!-- END Submit element -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the JS file,

```
$( '#user-data-form' ).submit( function(event) {
        alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can you please check if your js file is being fetched. You can go to network tab on chrome and check for the  js file name. if your .js file being called successfully have console log beginning of the js file and have console logs in your functions to check till where the script is running. any possibilities to see your code in action? because fiddle seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try making the `event.preventDefault();` the first thing that runs as the `alert` maybe allowing the normal button pressing function of a HTML form to get run while the alert sits on screen

```
$( '#user-data-form' ).submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    return false;
});
```

***As per your comment:***

Add the javascript before the

```
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

otherwise its not actually part of the DOM and wont get run

***As per your second comment***

Try putting your code inside a `.ready` like this. This ensures that the document is completely built before attempting to attach the .submit handler. And stops it attempting to add the handler before there is an object to attach it to in the DOM.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#user-data-form' ).submit( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just tried that, It didn't work either buddy. I have only added that alert to come up to indicate that it has been called, I should also add that the alert never appears.

Comment: Are you sure that the .js file is included in the html file. How is it included? Hard coded or a `<script...> tag?

Comment: I have the following at the bottom of the page before </body> & </html>

`<script src="js/test.js"></script>` 
@RiggsFolly

Comment: @John Don't include the js at the bottom of `</html>` it should be above `</html>`

Comment: Put in just before the `</body>`

Comment: @aldrin27 , sorry if I made you missunderstand but I have it before those tags as you can see [here](https://i.revo.pw/2874299_2877PE.png)

Comment: Try the second amendment. Not the one about bearing arms.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sorry I never got back. Had to go to sleep and was at work :)
I'm still trying to figure out the error. I have found that if I enter the JS code into the Console on chrome that then if I click the update button that the event is cancelled. What does this mean?

Comment: This works now, a buddy of mine fixed it using this and something else; it seems the JS was loading before the form was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your html:

```
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary" value="Update" id="SUBMIT">
```

JS:

```
 $('#SUBMIT').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var confirm = confirm('Message');
      if(confirm === true){
      //do something
      }else{ 
       return false;
      }
 });
```

Comment: I tried this buddy, sadly this did not work either. Thanks for the attempt though :)

Comment: But can you see the alert box appeared?

Comment: No, but i'm not sure if that's because the page is being reloaded due to the submission.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you must click first the button to submit. Not the form. Because it will trigger the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input submit to button and make an id. You can delete your id in your form and put that id in class.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered user-data-form">
<button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary" value="Update"></button>
```

OR

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered user-data-form">
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary" value="Update">
```

Then in your javascript calling the submit button

```
$('form.user-data-form #submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    return false;
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: still the same if you want input, not button <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary" value="Update"> Just add the (id="submit")